# Change XMLWriter Default Field Separator

Tags: php, field, separator, xmlwriter

I'm am looking to retrieving a bucketload of data from a Site, selecting specific sections of it, turning it into an XML Format, then importing it into a database (This question is about the XML Format Section)

the data received is a Raw Text file, that is distinguished into many different categories, however. The Field Separator used by this file is ":" and from my current experience, XMLWriter likes the Separator to be ","

is there any way I can change the Separator XMLWriter uses?

Current XML Code:

```
    <?php
$data = fopen('thing.txt', 'r');

    $xml = new XMLWriter;
    $xml->openURI('php://output');
    $xml->setIndent(true); // makes output cleaner

    $xml->startElement('Controllers');
    while ($line = fgetcsv($data)) {
       $xml->startElement('Current');
       $xml->writeElement('Callsign', $line[0]);
       $xml->writeElement('CID', $line[1]);
       $xml->writeElement('Name', $line[2]);
       $xml->endElement();
    }
    $xml->endElement();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLWriter is the part which creates the output, it doesn't know anything about the format of the file your reading.  This will be down to the call to [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). The third parameter to which is the delimiter you want to use, so change the read line to...

```
while ($line = fgetcsv($data, 0, ':')) {
```

Comment: That Worked! Thank you so Much!